# Does Sitecore 10.2 support async code?

Tags: sitecore-api

Say we have a SitecoreController which has async Task endpoints.. so my question is does sitecore support this async code? I have heard that there were some issues with async code while returning sitecore datasources and basically we only can have synch methods... is this true?

Thanks

Comment: You should never use/inherit from SitecoreController to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore does not support Async controller rendering. but from the **Sitecore 8.2 it supports async MVC controllers**.

If you want to use async actions, you need to use them outside of Sitecore contexts by indirectly invoking controllers via non-Sitecore routes or Html.RenderAction() on a Sitecore rendering. one other option is to use the AJAX base on your requirements.

But if you want to use that then follow - https://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/05/Enabling-Async-in-Sitecore-Controller-Renderings/

It’s a simple matter to patch Sitecore’s ControllerFactory, which is registered in the `<initialize>` pipeline:

```
<initialize>
    <processor type="Foo.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeAsyncControllerFactory, Foo.Core" patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeControllerFactory, Sitecore.Mvc']"/>
</initialize>

using Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;
using ControllerBuilder = System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder;
```

The class to override the controller factory:

```
namespace Foo.Pipelines.Initialize
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces the standard Sitecore MVC controller factory with one that knows how to do async action invocation.
    /// </summary>
    public class InitializeAsyncControllerFactory : InitializeControllerFactory
    {
        protected override void SetControllerFactory(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            SitecoreControllerFactory controllerFactory = new SitecoreAsyncControllerFactory(ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory());
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
        }
    }
}
```

Then override the way the `SitecoreControllerFactory patches` the `IActionInvoker` on the controllers:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Async;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers;

namespace Foo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Patches the normal Sitecore controller factory to enable executing async actions and using async/await
    /// The ActionInvoker that Sitecore MVC wraps the inner action invoker with does not implement IAsyncActionInvoker,
    /// which means ASP.NET MVC does not try to execute it async if needed, and precludes async/await.
    /// </summary>
    public class SitecoreAsyncControllerFactory : SitecoreControllerFactory
    {
        public SitecoreAsyncControllerFactory(IControllerFactory innerFactory) : base(innerFactory)
        {
        }

        protected override void PrepareController(IController controller, string controllerName)
        {
            if (!MvcSettings.DetailedErrorOnMissingAction)
            {
                return;
            }
            Controller controller2 = controller as Controller;
            if (controller2 == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            /* BEGIN PATCH FOR ASYNC INVOCATION (the rest of this method is stock) */
            IAsyncActionInvoker asyncInvoker = controller2.ActionInvoker as IAsyncActionInvoker;

            if (asyncInvoker != null)
            {
                controller2.ActionInvoker = new SitecoreAsyncActionInvoker(asyncInvoker, controllerName);
                return;
            }
            /* END PATCH FOR ASYNC INVOCATION */

            IActionInvoker actionInvoker = controller2.ActionInvoker;
            if (actionInvoker == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            controller2.ActionInvoker = new SitecoreActionInvoker(actionInvoker, controllerName);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, implement an override of `SitecoreActionInvoker` which implements `IAsyncActionInvoker`:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Async;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers;

namespace Foo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Literally all this does is provider an IAsyncActionInvoker wrapper the same way SitecoreActionInvoker wraps non-IAsyncActionInvokers
    /// This instructs ASP.NET MVC to perform async invocation for controller actions.
    /// </summary>
    public class SitecoreAsyncActionInvoker : SitecoreActionInvoker, IAsyncActionInvoker
    {
        private readonly IAsyncActionInvoker _innerInvoker;

        public SitecoreAsyncActionInvoker(IAsyncActionInvoker innerInvoker, string controllerName) : base(innerInvoker, controllerName)
        {
            _innerInvoker = innerInvoker;
        }

        public IAsyncResult BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            return _innerInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(controllerContext, actionName, callback, state);
        }

        public bool EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            return _innerInvoker.EndInvokeAction(asyncResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can go forth and write lovely async controller renderings!

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AsyncActionMethod()
{
    // download a bunch of URLs in parallel with await
    var webClient = new WebClient();

    var urls = new[] {
        "https://google.com",
        "https://bing.com",
        "https://yahoo.com"
    }.Select(url => webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url));

    var contents = await Task.WhenAll(urls);

    // or just await one task
    var google = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://google.com");

    // execution will pick up right here when all the awaited tasks are done - thawing the thread to finish execution

    return View(contents);
}
```